# How to Retrieve The Only Stored Entity From DataStore using Obectify efficiently

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I know only one entity of a specific kind is stored in datastore at a time.
How do i retrieve this entity using objectify v4 . what load query/operation will do this.
I dont know the ID of entity, so cant query by ID.

I am currently using 
   ofy().load.type(MyObject.class).list();

Is there a better option.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the `Id` of the entity then the other option is to query by the entity's `Key`, which can be achieved as follows:

```
MyObject entity = ofy().load().key(myObjectKey).now();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the key, get the key. Cache it in a static (application-scoped) variable in your app. This is one keys-only query the first time you need the value in an instance.

Then load the value by key directly each time. Make sure you have `@Cache` on the entity class. Your load-by-key operation will effectively be a memcache hit every time.